# RISCV C to hex Compilation for UART

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files, riscv

I am trying to convert UART loopback program to corresponding hex code. The command

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc test.c -march=rv32im
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -o test test.c
```

both the command giving error

```
test.c:2:10: fatal error: rt/rt_api.h: No such file or directory
 #include <rt/rt_api.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

what is the exact command for compiling the **C** code with APIs, I am using Pulppissimo toolchain..
my program is
https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-rt-examples/tree/master/periph/uart/loopback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because rt/rt_api.h is not present in your riscv gcc search path.
To see the folders present in search path you can add `-v` option to your command or use:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-cpp -v /dev/null /dev/null
```

What you can do is find the location of rt/rt_api.h and giving the path you find to gcc. Your command will be:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -o test test.c -Ipath
```